# Dirty Flash Android Kernel

Tags: kernel

Will it be an issue if I dirty flash android kernel? I am trying out a few kernels for my phone and I want to make sure that dirty flashing won't affect the efficiency of the kernel. If it does, what is the method to flash a new kernel without losing data and apps?

Comment: Booting a new kernel image on an existing system is quite usual, especially as `fastboot` allows to do so even without flashing the kernel image: Just execute `fastboot boot <kernelimage.img>` to boot a kernel image from your PC.

Comment: BTW, "dirty flashing" a kernel is quite normal... Flash the (I assume) custom kernel and follow any process the kernel dev recommends, which is typically no make than wipe caches. There should be no reason in most cases to have to wipe data when flashing a new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Use twrp to flash the kernels.
Always keep a flashable zip of the stock kernel, in case you face any problem.
I have seen requirements of many kernel developers that,
you need to be on stock kernel before flashing the custom one. So, before flashing another custom kernel, it is always recommended to flash the stock one, then flash the custom one.